# Is there a way to specify an already created s3 deployment bucket in serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

So we are currently using serverless in our recent project and our client provided us the aws iam user because we will be deploying into their aws resources. The problem is that they won't give create s3 policy to the user. The creation of the s3 bucket will be done by them manually. So where in the serverless.yml can i add the s3 bucket they created and have serverless use it as a deployment bucket instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the OP is asking about how to specify the Serverless S3 deployment bucket, not how to reference a random bucket in a Lambda function.

You can set the deployment bucket in `serverless.yml` like this:

```
provider:
    deploymentBucket: <bucket name>
```

Comment: Yeah its only for deployment bucket. I see, so only the bucket name? Not the ARN?

Comment: Serverless docs say it is only the bucket name. Since S3 buckets are globally unique it is easy to calculate the ARN from that

Comment: Also, https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3060 is worth a read if you came here wondering how/if it's possible to configure the path inside an S3 bucket (in short, not yet supported. If you have 10 serverless projects, you need 10 S3 buckets).

Comment: If you have 10 Serverless projects, you do not need 10 S3 buckets. Serverless will generate a unique zip file name from the project name, the stage name and a timestamp. Unless you have a need to restrict S3 paths for IAM reasons you can share a bucket across Serverless projects. See https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3060#issuecomment-339020677

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters within the serverless application cloud formation script:

```
"Parameters" : {
  "S3BucketArn" : {
    "Default" : "arn:aws:s3:::somebucketarndefaults",
    "Description" : "The ARN for the S3 Bucket",
    "Type" : "String"
  }
}
```

I'm guessing you're using this in a serverless function (Lambda), so you can pass this using the environment variables

```
 "Resources" : {
    "MyAmazingFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "functions::handle",
        // Yada yada
    "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            "S3Arn": {"Ref" : "S3BucketArn"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then within the code just pull out the Arn using `S3Arn` environment variable.